# How to get the picture to appear after the textbox using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to send emails  to my partners and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the text (from the text box) to appear after the picture. And when I change the code to do so- the format of the text is lost. here is the code

```
Sub send_mass_email()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name, email, body, subject, copy, place, business As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
    
    i = 2
    
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        
        name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0) 'extract first name
        email = Cells(i, 2).Value
        subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
        copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
        business = Cells(i, 5).Value
        place = Cells(i, 6).Value
        
        
        body = Replace(body, "C1", name)
        body = Replace(body, "C5", business)
        body = Replace(body, "C6", place)
    
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
             .to = email
             .cc = copy
             .subject = subject
             .body = body
             .HTMLBody = "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/4gVsz56/fastpass.png'> " & _
             .HTMLBody
             .display
             '.Send
             
        End With
        
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
            
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody, "Setting the HTMLBody property will always update the Body property immediately.".  I don't think that you can use both.  Can you use just HTMLBody?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `.Body` AND `.HTMLBody` as they do not work together... you want something like this

```
    With OutMail
         .to = email
         .cc = copy
         .subject = subject
         .HTMLBody = body & "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/4gVsz56/fastpass.png'>"
         ' or use this line
         '.HTMLBody = body & "<br><img src='https://i.ibb.co/4gVsz56/fastpass.png'>"
         .display
         '.Send
    End With
```

Comment: thanks- I appreciate the input- however when I do that the format of the text is lost and shows as 1 paragraph in stead of 3 separate ones which is what the text box has.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but then just use `.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/4gVsz56/fastpass.png'>"` - see how you just put the IMG code last instead of `.HTMLBody` being last?

Comment: If you need 3 separate lines, you can just use the html `<br>` tag to create a new line instead of the way you are doing it.

Comment: that didn't work either :(. Might be hard to explain- but the excel sheet has their name, email, etc and i'm trying to send a personalized email that will insert their name, company, etc which is why i am using the text box on the spread sheet. So when I use the top code- the text shows up perfectly but the picture shows above it. when I change it to show under- the text then loses all format and is just bunched together.

Comment: lol also- i don't know what i'm doing which is why i'm using code that doesn't work with each other :)

Comment: I would avoid using the textbox just so you can get multiple lines. Build the string for HTMLBody each time in the loop, and use `<br>` when you need to start a new line. The way you are doing it is unnecessarily complicated. The `<br>` tags turn into new lines when they are rendered by HTMLBody.

Comment: I was using the text box just so I could write the desired message with inserts- so it automatically replaces the persons name and company. I'm not really sure how to build separate loops to accomplish the same thing. I figured this would be a nice template because when I want to do another bulk email- I just have to change the text in the text box.

Comment: I would be happy to pay you for help in making something that is easy to change in the future

Comment: You can also try `body = Replace(body, vbCr, "<br>")` which should convert the vb lines to HTML lines. (after you are done building it from the textbox)

Comment: if `vbCr` doesn't work, you can also try `vbCrLf` or `vbLf` - either way, you need to convert the vba new line characters to html if you want new lines AND the picture...